# Error attempting to create a multiomic object with the MOFA2 package in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using the MOFA2 package based on a vignette outlined [here](https://raw.githack.com/bioFAM/MOFA2_tutorials/master/R_tutorials/microbiome_vignette.html) and have merged three layers of omic data (metabolome, inflammatory factors, and microbiome) in a long format dataframe in the columns required (i.e., 'sample', 'feature', 'value', and 'view'.

```
> head(multiomic)
   sample              feature      value       view
1 SM01_01 X2_Aminobutyric.acid 0.05117221 metabolome
2 SM01_02 X2_Aminobutyric.acid 0.03615312 metabolome
3 SM01_03 X2_Aminobutyric.acid 0.15299858 metabolome
4 SM02_01 X2_Aminobutyric.acid 0.13094635 metabolome
5 SM02_02 X2_Aminobutyric.acid 0.63106917 metabolome
6 SM02_03 X2_Aminobutyric.acid 0.70794188 metabolome

> str(multiomic)
'data.frame':   26208 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ sample : chr  "SM01_01" "SM01_02" "SM01_03" "SM02_01" ...
 $ feature: Factor w/ 222 levels "X2_Aminobutyric.acid",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value  : num  0.0512 0.0362 0.153 0.1309 0.6311 ...
 $ view   : chr  "metabolome" "metabolome" "metabolome" "metabolome" ...
```

When attempting to run the command to create a MOFA object I get this error message:

```
> create_mofa_from_df(multiomic)
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : values must be type 'logical',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'integer'
```

I tried with just the metabolome and inflammation merged data, and it worked. I believe there is an issue with the microbiome data, but not sure where the issue is arising. I have formatted exactly as in the vigette mentioned above. Looking at the data structure for the microbiome data (i.e., 'data') vs. the combined metabolomic and inflammation data (i.e., 'mulit_long') yields the following:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   8424 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ sample : chr  "SM01_01" "SM26_01" "SM30_03" "SM02_01" ...
 $ feature: chr  "Bifidobacterium" "Blautia" "Bacteroides" "Blautia" ...
 $ value  : num  7.97 7.85 7.77 7.77 7.73 ...
 $ view   : chr  "microbiome" "microbiome" "microbiome" "microbiome" ...

> str(multi_long)
'data.frame':   17784 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ sample : chr  "SM01_01" "SM01_02" "SM01_03" "SM02_01" ...
 $ feature: Factor w/ 152 levels "X2_Aminobutyric.acid",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value  : num  0.0512 0.0362 0.153 0.1309 0.6311 ...
 $ view   : chr  "metabolome" "metabolome" "metabolome" "metabolome" ...
```

I'm guessing this is a structural issue and I'm just missing the obvious solution... Appreciate any guidance!

Thank you

Comment: I get the same error, so I have tried with head() and I have a clue where is the error, but it looks normal, so I do not know how to fix it. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error until I realized that I had NAs in my first column (the ID or group column). So, in my case, the data structure was not exactly the same as the microbiome dataset.